# I want to show Sub menu li tags are inactive

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
<ul class="nav" id="shop">
<li class="active">
     <a>Type</a> 

   <ul id="category" class="nav1">
   <li ><a>Bulb</a></li>
    <li><a>Focus light</a></li>
    <li><a>Downlight</a></li>
    <li><a>Touch</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>  



  <li><a>Engery</a></li>
   <li><a>Link 3</a></li>

</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

  $( ' ul#shop li' ).on( 'click', function() {
            $( this ).parent().find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
      });

      $( ' ul#category li' ).on( 'click', function() {
            $( this ).parent().find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
      });
});
```

I want to show `parent li` tag is active TYPE ,their children tag are inactive.

When I click anyone child tag , the `child li` and `parent li` is active. Remaining children tag are inactive

EXCEPTED OUTPUT:
Before clicking the child node

```
TYPE //active
     Bulb    //inactive
     Focus light    //inactive
     Down light  //inactive
     Touch   //inactive
```

After  clicking  the child node (Down light)

```
TYPE //active
         Bulb    //inactive
         Focus light    //inactive
         Down light  //active
         Touch   //inactive
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9ff79/707/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

   $( ' ul#shop li a' ).on( 'click', function() {
            $( this ).parent().siblings().find( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).siblings("#category").addClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
      });

       $( ' #category li ' ).on( 'click', function() {
            $( this ).parent("#category").find( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).parent("#category").parent().find(' > a').addClass( 'active' );
            $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
      }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<style>
  ul.nav a { cursor: pointer; }
  .active { 
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bolder;
   }
</style>
<body>
<ul class="nav" id="shop">
<li>
     <a>Type</a> 

   <ul id="category" class="nav1">
   <li ><a>Bulb</a></li>
    <li><a>Focus light</a></li>
    <li><a>Downlight</a></li>
    <li><a>Touch</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>  



  <li><a>Engery</a></li>
   <li><a>Link 3</a></li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```